# Z-order issue with MediaCodec and TextureView

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-mediacodec, textureview

In my Android app I have the need to render three views with the following Z-order:

1. At bottom, the output surface of a `MediaCodec` decoder covering the whole screen.  I have the requirement that I have to transform the image produced by `MediaCodec` (e.g. scale it)
2. In the middle, a `GLSurfaceView` (or other surface/view running GL shaders I define), covering the whole screen.  Obviously some of the pixels in this layer will be transparent, in order to see the `MediaCodec` output beneath.
3. On top, any other view - say an `ImageView`.  Not sure if I will require transparency for these topmost views, maybe fully opaque rectangular Views are OK - they just won't cover the whole screen and will move around.

It's looking like this is impossible but maybe I'm missing something or there is a way to do it with more effort at a lower level (e.g. EGL contexts or something like that...which I currently don't understand).

The reason I haven't been able to get this to work and am worrying it is impossible is:

- For the bottom `MediaCodec` output layer (1), I have to be able to transform the image.  So, the surface I give MediaCodec to render to must be from a `TextureView`
- In order to be able to see through the transparent pixels of the middle `GLSurfaceView` (2), I have to call `GLSurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true)`.  Otherwise the GLSurfaceView is opaque.
- But calling `GLSurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true)` means that no other views (3) are rendered on top of the `GLSurfaceView`.  E.g. an `ImageView` will always appear behind the opaque pixels of the `GLSurfaceView`.

It looks like calling `GLSurfaceView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true)` instead of `GLSurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true)` is intended to address this and facilitate this type of Z-ordering.  And it does if the bottommost `MediaCodec` output layer is a `SurfaceView`.  But I need it to be a `TextureView` so I can transform it.  And `GLSurfaceView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true)` doesn't seem to work when there is a `TextureView` beneath it:  the `TextureView` is completely obscured by the middle `GLSurfaceView` layer rather than showing through the transparent pixels.

Is it correct that this Z-ordering is impossible?  Or can it be accomplished by messing around with EGL and contexts, etc?

Answer (score 2):

EGL contexts aren't really relevant here.  Your fight is with SurfaceFlinger and the view system.

If you run `adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger` you can see something a complete list of all the layers that the system compositor knows about.  If you're playing a 320x240 video in a `SurfaceView`, it looks something like this (several columns and lots of other stuff removed for brevity):

```
    type    |          source crop              |           frame           name 
------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------------
        HWC | [    0.0,    0.0,  320.0,  240.0] | [   48,  411, 1032, 1149] SurfaceView
        HWC | [    0.0,   75.0, 1080.0, 1776.0] | [    0,   75, 1080, 1776] com.android.grafika/com.android.grafika.PlayMovieSurfaceActivity
        HWC | [    0.0,    0.0, 1080.0,   75.0] | [    0,    0, 1080,   75] StatusBar
        HWC | [    0.0,    0.0, 1080.0,  144.0] | [    0, 1776, 1080, 1920] NavigationBar
  FB TARGET | [    0.0,    0.0, 1080.0, 1920.0] | [    0,    0, 1080, 1920] HWC_FRAMEBUFFER_TARGET
```

The layers are in Z-order, from back to front.  The SurfaceView's surface layer is at the back, the app UI layer is on top of that, and the system status + nav bars are above everything.

Everything in the app's View hierarchy is rendered on a single layer.  That includes `TextureView`.  You can't control its Z-ordering relative to other hardware-composited layers.

`SurfaceView`is fancy in that the View portion is just a transparent placeholder, while the real action happens on that separate layer, whose Z-ordering you can control (a little).  You can put it on three different levels:

- "media" (the default)
- "media overlay"
- (app UI is here)
- "panel" (ZOrderOnTop)

So what you want to do is put your `MediaCodec` output at the default layer, and your GLES output at the "media overlay" layer.  You need to do both of these with a `SurfaceView`.

It's hard to provide better advice from here because you described the problems you're having with your attempted solution, rather than the problem you're trying to solve (i.e. what are you building?), but I can offer a couple of suggestions.

First, you *can* scale a SurfaceView.  If you look at the dumpsys output above, you'll notice that the "SurfaceView" line has a source crop rect of 320x240 (the size of the video), and a destination rect that's 984x738.  This is coming from [Grafika's](https://github.com/google/grafika) "Play video (SurfaceView)", which sized the SurfaceView to preserve the 4:3 aspect ratio of the video.  SurfaceFlinger takes care of scaling the content to match the view.

Second, if you're not showing DRM-protected video content, you can send it to a `SurfaceTexture` and just render it with GLES when you're rendering everything else.  (This is exactly what `TextureView` does, which is why it requires hardware acceleration.)  See e.g. "Continuous capture" in Grafika.

**Update:** a much longer description can be found in the [Android System-Level Graphics doc](http://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html).

Comment: There is an api setZOrderOnTop in SurfaceView, but there is no such api in TexutureView, If  I use textureView and want to do the thing that setZOrderOnTop does, How to do it? Now I suffered it a lot. And there is an api setFormat in SurfaceHolder. How to do the things that setFormat does if I use TextureView?

Comment: @dragonfly: there is no need for either of those in TextureView. TextureView output is written to the View UI layer, just like any other UI widget. You position the Z-order with layout calls or XML. The color format is the color format of the View UI, which will be RGBA8888 on modern devices.